# What's the most effective way to align 1x1 tiles?

Tags: building

There are a number of sets (e.g., the Farnsworth House and the Parisian Restaurant) that use a field of 1x1 tiles to represent a tiled floor. I have found aligning these pieces such that they are all square to each other to be a challenge. What techniques can I try to achieve a nicely aligned grid of tiles?

For example:

[image]

Comment: I've used credit cards or library cards for this kind of thing,  but you need enough room for it. Protip: credit cards can also help straighten bent CPU pins.

Answer (score 10):

I will sometimes take another piece, i.e. a 1x4, next to the row I'm about to place so it helps align it. Then use the brick separator's flat end to adjust the 1x1 as needed. But I'm a little ocd about the tiles being lined up...

Answer (score 5):

For a number of sets that I've had these in (the Minecraft Mirco-worlds and the Scientists Ideas set) they've also come with one of the new orange Brick tools.

You can use the edge of the tool to run along between the sides of the tiles and the next row of studs - I find this works better than using another plate or brick because the tool has more play over the studs so can actually get up against the edges of the tiles nicely.

Answer (score 1):

My method is to use a 2x8 (or longer) plate like a pry bar. Put the 2-stud end on the studs next to the tiles and pry up a little and they line up like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Placement is key - line up before pushing all the way down onto stud. (Though this is easier for 1x1 bricks... Less so for tiles)
Also the curved end of brick separator works nicely to make fine adjustments. Need to push and rock middle of edge of tile.. if you try the edge you always over shoot and end up pushing the other way too much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tweezers you can use them to grab the tile put it in place with them then push down.